# How to get/access row value from Repeater using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, repeater, getelementbyid

i've a jquery function for my textbox onchange event. when triggers, i want to validate the value inputted by the user in the textbox with the value from the datatable displayed by repeater. i was able to get the value of the textbox but my problem is i cant get the value (qty column) from the repeater. i put on an itemindex for the id of the row to identify the right row and get the value of column qty. in debugging mode, the variable that i used is unidentified so im not getting any value at all. I need help please, i've been struggling for this too long now.

html

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInStock" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="ucprodres-in-stock<%# Container.ItemIndex%>>" class="ucprodres-in-stock">
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock manufacturer">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="instock-qtyavail" class="ucprodres-stock qty-avail">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock availability">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Availability").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock unit-price">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("QtyRange").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock dollar">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("QtyRangePrice").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock qty-required instock-qtyreqd">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxInStock" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

jquery: (+itemIndex is not working also, how do i add index to the id since i used container.itemIndex to make my ids unique?)

```
function ValidateQty1(txtBox) {
    var qtyreqd = txtBox.value;
    var instockrow = document.getElementById("ucprodres-in-stock" + itemIndex);
    var qtyavail = instockrow.childNodes[1].nodeValue;
    if (qtyreqd > qtyavail) {
        alert("The required quantity should not be greater than the available quantity");
}
```

sample generated html

```
<div id="ucprodres-in-stock">

                <div id="ucprodres-in-stock0>" class="ucprodres-in-stock">
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock manufacturer">
                        FAIRCHILD SEMICONDUCTOR C
                    </div>
                    <div id="instock-qtyavail" class="ucprodres-stock qty-avail">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock availability">
                        In Stock
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock unit-price">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock dollar">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock qty-required instock-qtyreqd">

                        <input name="MasterBasic$MasterPageContent$ucProductHeader$ucProductResults$rptInStock$ctl00$tbxInStock" type="text" id="MasterPageContent_ucProductHeader_ucProductResults_rptInStock_tbxInStock_0" onchange="ValidateQty1(this);" onkeypress="return validate(event);" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="ucprodres-in-stock1>" class="ucprodres-in-stock">
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock manufacturer">
                        Fairchild Semiconductor Corp
                    </div>
                    <div id="instock-qtyavail" class="ucprodres-stock qty-avail">
                        6
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock availability">
                        In Stock
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock unit-price">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock dollar">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock qty-required instock-qtyreqd">

                        <input name="MasterBasic$MasterPageContent$ucProductHeader$ucProductResults$rptInStock$ctl01$tbxInStock" type="text" id="MasterPageContent_ucProductHeader_ucProductResults_rptInStock_tbxInStock_1" onchange="ValidateQty1(this);" onkeypress="return validate(event);" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here's a sample output to better understand my scenario: when onchange triggered, i want to get the value in qty-avail where the txtbox was changed.

[image]

**UPDATES:**
Jquery Function:

```
function ValidateQty1(txtBox) {
    var qtyreqd = txtBox.value;
    var qtyavail = $(this).parent().siblings(".qty-avail").text().trim();
    alert(qtyavail);
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInStock" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="ucprodres-in-stock<%# Container.ItemIndex%>" class="ucprodres-in-stock">
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock manufacturer">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="instock-qtyavail" class="ucprodres-stock qty-avail">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock availability">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Availability").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock unit-price">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("QtyRange").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock dollar">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("QtyRangePrice").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock qty-required instock-qtyreqd">
                        <input type="text" onkeypress="return validate(event);" onchange="ValidateQty1(this);"  />
                        <%--<asp:TextBox ID="tbxInStock" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X5Q4H/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nth-of-type` with JQuery to find an item by index, something similar to:

```
<script>
var foundEl = $( "#ucprodres-in-stock > div:nth-of-type(2)" );
</script>
```

Here is the link to the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/

For example:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
     <section id="demo">
            <!-- some code-->
     </section>
     <section id="test">
            <!-- some code-->
     </section>
     <section id="hello">
            <!-- some code-->
     </section>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

This will print "test" in the console:

```
var el =$("form>fieldset>section:nth-child(2)");
console.log(el.attr("id"));
```

**Update 1:**

Based on your resent update here is how I would do it, I would search for the parent siblings with the class `.qty-avail`, something like:

```
$("input").on('change',function(){
    var t = $(this).parent().siblings(".qty-avail").text().trim();
    alert(t);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5Q4H/1
or 
as it is in your code sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/X5Q4H/2/

Comment: howabout the suffix? do i still need to append it to the id ucprodres-in-stock? i put a suffix to identify each row? wont i need it anymore?

Comment: with nth-of-type it will not be necessary to sufix divs to find them

Comment: its working but im getting the whole table value if without the suffix. i need to identify the row by using the properties of txtbox like if i can get the index so that i can append it to the row div id.

Comment: im not looking for the txtbox because the onchange event handles that already, what i need is the value of the qty-avail of the same row where the txtbox was changed. without the suffix, i get all the value of the second column in the repeater. im thinking of using the properties of the textbox since it is the one that i have, can i locate the row index using this?

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to use fiddle. just new in web developing. i've added an image to better explain what i need to do. ucprodres-in-stock is the div id (of each row). can i get that id name using the txtbox onchange event? when debugging i can see the properties of the txtbox, included in there is the parentElement but i do not know how i can access or get it. i think that will solve my problem.

Comment: i tried the following to get the parentElement value but its not working:
1. var parentElem = txtbox.parent();
2. var parentElem = $(txtbox).parent();

Comment: check this fiddle and let me know if it is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/X5Q4H/1/

Comment: yeah! this is exactly what i need.. i tried it in my code.. im getting a null value though i used textbox and in there is a input.. a little cleaning in my codes and i think it will work.. thanks a lot.. and i'll feedback again once this one is working in my code..

Comment: argh! im getting a null value. i get the value from the textbox but the value in the column is null. howabout using childnode? parent.childnode?

Comment: i tried doing exactly what's on the fiddle, the onchange event wont fire so i went back using asp textbox and add ontextchanged attr on the server-side then call the function. then i included in that function your codes. it supposed to be just like that right?

Comment: i updated my post, please see if there's something i am missing.

Comment: finally got it! i use $(txtbox) instead of $(this)... thank you so much for your help and for being so patient with me... hope everyone here is like you to beginners like me... thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

The id's of the divs you're trying to select have a rogue > character in them.

```
id="ucprodres-in-stock0>"
```

Also what you have here is pure JavaScript. There is no jQuery usage.